# Mysql - add ranking column to view error - View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter

Tags: mysql

I got an error "View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter" when adding ranking to the view as below

```
CREATE TABLE enrol_note
(
enrol_id INT,
note VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO enrol_note
VALUES
(1,'a1'),
(2,'a2'),
(2,'a3'),
(2,'a4'),
(3,'a5'),
(3,'a6'),
(4,'a7');
```

I can select and add ranking column to it.

```
SELECT n.*, IF( @prev <> enrol_id, @rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum+1 ) AS ranking
,@prev := enrol_id 
FROM enrol_note n
JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @prev := 0) AS r
```

[image]

However, I got error when copy this script to the view.
[image]

I know it's a limitation of MySQL but still looking for a workaround to solve it (without using the variable as above or RANK() function because MySQL version does not support that)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Without an order by your query is not robust.  also are the notes unique?

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) says limitations about VIEWs.

- The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the from clause
- SELECT statement cannot refer to system variables or user-defined var
- You cannot associate a trigger with a view.

and so on.